# How to use Perl to grep specific information from many files in a list of directories

Tags: regex, perl

I have a directory structure like this

```
$workdir/XXXX/YYYY.log.
```

where `XXXX` is the sub directory name (there are many sub directories) and `YYYY` is the log file name (there are many log files also).

I need to extract some information from all the logs. Currently I use

```
@Info = qx(grep "information" -r $workdir)
```

and then output the `@Info` to a file to do this.

Is there a more efficient way to do this?

Comment: Why do you need something "more efficient"? Is there a performance problem?  You could improve on this approach only if the directories contain a lot of files you don't want to scan.

Comment: Hi @JimGarrison , thanks for reply. It was because sometimes the number of sub directories and log files may be huge, when run this script under that circumstance, it looks the program will be "dead" for a few minutes before gives the output.

Answer (score 1):

I would use something like this in pure Perl. I think a lot of the problem is that there is no reassurance that the process is progressing. This solution prints the name of each subdirectory and each log file to STDERR as it is encountered, but send all the grepped lines to STDOUT.

You will have to modify the condition in the `while` loop so the the correct lines are selected.

It wouldn't be too hard to produce a "percent complete" figure, or an estimated time of completion, if that is what you wish.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use autodie;

use File::Spec;

my $workdir = '/path/to/work/dir';

opendir my($dh), '.';
my @subdirs = grep { -d and /\A[^.]/ } readdir $dh;
closedir $dh;

for my $subdir (@subdirs) {
  $subdir = File::Spec->catdir($workdir, $subdir);
  print STDERR "$subdir\n";

  opendir my($dh), $subdir;
  my @logs = grep { /\.log\z/i } readdir $dh;
  closedir $dh;

  @logs = grep { -f } map { File::Spec->catfile($subdir, $_) } @logs
  for my $log (@logs) {
    print STDERR "  $log\n";
    open my $fh, '<', $log;
    while (<$fh>) {
      print "    $_" if /condition/;
    }
  }
}
```